# Loading a file that contains hex values into a char array

Tags: c, arrays

this may seem basic to some of you, but please try to help me!

I have created a BMP file that stores a 4 x 3 image. The content of this file (FILEHEADER, FILEINFOHEADER, color bytes, and padding, are represented in hex).

I'm trying to write a loadFile function to load the BMP file and store it into a 2D array of integers.

I'm first trying to figure out how to store the content of the file into a character array, then i would try and do a strcpy of the char array and convert that into int values (i'm not converting yet).

But for now i've attempted to load the file and put into a char array... (it doesn't work, but i was hoping to get some feedback on whether or not i'm in the right direction), and how would i go about approaching this problem!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define length 30
#define rows   7

int main()
{

FILE *myBmp;
myBmp = fopen("myBmp.bmp", "r"); //for now i'm not sure what the r is for

//read file into array
char hexArray[rows][length];
int c;

for (c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
    fscanf(myBmp, "%c", &hexArray[c]);
}

for (c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
    printf("Number is: %c\n", hexArray[c]);
}

fclose(myBmp);
}
```

Comment: The BMP bitmap format has nothing in common with the 0-terminated text string required by `strcpy`, perhaps explore `memcpy`.

Comment: Why not use a library like [QDBMP](http://qdbmp.sourceforge.net/) that does all this stuff and more for you?

Comment: BTW, the `"r"` in `fopen("myBmp.bmp", "r")` stands for "read mode"

Comment: The `length` and `rows` are data you should extract from the BMP header. There are a lot of previous SO questions about reading/making BMP files.

Comment: I think you're confused about data representations. BMP headers and data are unencoded data bytes. You don't read them with `fscanf`. That's for ASCII-encoded text. You read them with something like `fread`. Your confusion may lie in your use of some kind of hex dump tool that shows the values as hex strings.  That's just for your convenience. Each pair of hex characters is representing one raw byte. They could also be shown as 3 decimal digits, 3 octal digits, or 8 one/zeros.

Comment: You also want to use "br" in the fopen call - the `b` for binary.

Comment: Bottomline, you need to read up on the BMP format before you begin parsing BMPs.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! The QDBMP library was specially helpful to look at!